# get contents of all <p> tags inside <div> using html parser Hpple in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xpath, hpple

I want to parse the following html code for my iphone application

```
<Html>
<body>
<div class="div_1">
    <div class="div_2">some code....</div>
    <div class="div_3">
        <div class="div_4">
            <div class="div_5">
                <p>First Paragraph</p>
                <p>Second Paragraph</p>
                <p>Third Paragraph</p>
                <p>Fourth Paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</Html>
```

I am using Hpple parser for parsing this html. 
The xpath query that I am using is

```
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:getHTMLData];

NSArray *elementsToSearch = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@class='div_5']/p"];

TFHppleElement *element = [elementsToSearch objectAtIndex:0];
```

What I intent to get is all the p tag contents inside of div class="div_5".
Using the above xpath query i am only getting the first p tag contents i.e "First Paragraph".
Am i doing anything wrong in my xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The results are all in `elementsToSearch` returned by `-searchWithXPathQuery`.

Try to check out:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[elementsToSearch description]);
```